# Ubuntu 15.10 frozen GUI after update

Tags: update-manager, gui, 15.10

I installed 15.10 on my Dell Inspirion and all was working well -

after updates with updatemanager and reboot - the GUI is "frozen" after login.. no mousepointer - no keyboard... no items in the titleline (date, settings, wlan usw..) only a black headerline...

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 - Reinstall Ubuntu desktop**

Instead of logging into Ubuntu through the GUI, once you are at the login page:

- Press CTRL + ALT + F1
- On the shell prompt, input your user and password
- Try reinstalling Ubuntu Desktop:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

**Option 2 - GUI Still broken**

Assuming you have another computer, just download 15.10 Version from www.ubuntu.com, burn it to an USB using `unetbootin` http://unetbootin.org/, and boot your Ubuntu-PC with the USB plugged in. On the Ubuntu installation, choose the option "Reinstall".

This will keep all your files and upgrade your whole system.

If you cannot boot from the USB, change your boot settings in the bios.

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: Cheers. Don't forget then to mark the answer as correct, so other users see that solution is the right one.

Comment: Hi SchlaWienER, don't forget to mark Eduardo's answer as correct.